# Firebase Pagination using startAt with value and Key not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I'm trying to setup a pagination for a search page in mobile app developed in ionic3. The search results always fetched only the first 5 values even if the key is provided.
I tried to put a different key but still the issue exists.
Please find the code below

```
this.storeListRefss$ = this.db.list(`/productList/` + this.storeId + `/`, {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'product_name_search',
    limitToFirst: 5,
    startAt:  { value: 'milk', key: '-L2Z8INhE8mFA4fWwiGk' },
    endAt: self.searchValue + "\uf8ff"
  }
});

this.storeListRefss$.subscribe((result) => {
  result.forEach((element) => {
    self.searchResults.push(element);
  });
  console.log(this.searchResults);
});
```

This is the sample json data iam pulling from the firebase

```
{
  "-L2Z8Gvp-T5O3r46dQO4" : {
    "product_desc" : "",
    "product_img" : "",
    "product_name" : "2-POCKET PAPER FOLDER",
    "product_name_search" : "2-pocket paper folder",
    "product_reg_price" : "0.7900",
    "product_sales_price" : "0.7900",
    "product_upc" : "718103177610",
    "status" : 1
  },
  "-L2Z8Gvp-T5O3r46dQO5" : {
    "product_desc" : "",
    "product_img" : "",
    "product_name" : "3 MUSKETEERS BITES",
    "product_name_search" : "3 musketeers bites",
    "product_reg_price" : "1.9900",
    "product_sales_price" : "1.9900",
    "product_upc" : "040000422471",
    "status" : 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the JSON you're querying (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data)? It'd also be good if you reproduce the problems with hard-coded values, instead of `self.searchValue` and `self.keyPagination`, as we have no way to know what those are.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i have added the json and the hardcorded the values for references.

Comment: There is no property `name_search` in your JSON. You probably meant to use `product_name_search`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry for that,i have re-edited the code, i lost it during pasting it to stackoverflow. The issue is still there even using the  " product_name_search "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on an old version of AngularFire which doesn't support the second argument for `startAt()` or `endAt()` in the query API.

You have two options: upgrade to the new api or create a reference and pass it into the `list()` method. I recommend upgrading to the new version 5 API which is much simpler. But I'll detail both below.

**Option 1 - Create a reference instead of using the Query API**

```
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  const ref = db.database.ref(`/productList/` + this.storeId);
  const query = ref
                 .orderByChild('product_name_search')
                 .limitToFirst(5)
                 .startAt('milk', '-L2Z8INhE8mFA4fWwiGk')
                 .endAt(self.searchValue + "\uf8ff");
  const list$ = db.list(query);
}
```

**Option 2 - Upgrade to the new API**

```
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  const list$ = db.list(`/productList/` + this.storeId, ref => {
    return ref
            .orderByChild('product_name_search')
            .limitToFirst(5)
            .startAt('milk', '-L2Z8INhE8mFA4fWwiGk')
            .endAt(this.searchValue + "\uf8ff");
  }).valueChanges();
}
```